# Visual Studio Code Preference

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a small preview window (right hand side) in Visual Studio Code that I would like to hide. After searching around I haven't found anything and not sure what the name of this feature is.

Is there a setting to turn this off?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is outlined in the documentation

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

You must go to your user or workspace settings and set

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, that was it. I think your answer is missing a beginning quote. I'll accept the answer after the time limit has expired.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)